# On click of a custom button i need message to popup

Tags: apex, visualforce

On click of a custom button i need a Confirmation pop-up like OK or CANCEL ,   If we click ok then it should proceed to the  operation , if cancel then just no action close the pop-up.( Not in Javascript/ Jquery)

Sample Pop-up like below. Any idea to achieve this

[image: apex]

**Visual force page:**

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true"  standardController="Enrollment__c" extensions="ConvertToFamilies" >

<script> 
window.onload = function toggleModal() {
    document.getElementById('successmessage').style.display = 'none';
    var element = document.getElementById('myModal');
    element.classList.toggle("slds-fade-in-open");
    var backdrop =  document.getElementById('backdrop');
    backdrop.classList.toggle("slds-backdrop_open"); 

}


</script>

<html>
    <head>

        <script>
        function toggleModal() {
            document.getElementById('successmessage').style.display = 'none';
            var element = document.getElementById('myModal');
            element.classList.toggle("slds-fade-in-open");
            var backdrop =  document.getElementById('backdrop');
            backdrop.classList.toggle("slds-backdrop_open");    
        }
        </script>
        <apex:slds />
    </head>
    <body onLoad="toggleModal()">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <section id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <h3 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Are you sure want to Convert as Families!</h3>                  
                    </header>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onClick="window.history.back();">No</button>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Yes</button> 

                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div id="backdrop" class="slds-backdrop"></div>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Added my VF page code above. in this it's opening in another page, want to implement in same page. (Need to Implement Salesforce standard modal in a Detail page button)

The above VF page open like below, I'm trying to open the model in the same page like my first screen shot

[image]

Comment: What have you done and do you have any current code/component to share? I'd suggest an [edit] to your post to provide the information.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves  Edited my question, Sorry for inconvenience.